# Перевести программу с Паскаля на [любой-язык]

Tags: любой-язык, соревнование

Конкурс окончен, смотрите результаты в конце вопроса.

---

Я думаю, многие из вас видели вопросы, состоящие из просьбы перевода программы с одного языка на другой. Давайте-ка покажем, как делать такие вещи правильно! В нашем конкурсе мы исходим из такой простой программы на Паскале:

```pascal
program test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c := a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.
```

([Она же на ideone](http://ideone.com/3fi4S4).)

**Задание** состоит в следующем: вы должны перевести программу на [любой-язык](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba) так, чтобы сохранить как можно больше от исходного текста программы. В качестве целевого языка, понятно, исключаются языки группы Паскаля (Delphi, Algol, Oberon, Modula, etc., все языки, в которых используется `begin`/`end` для группировки команд в составную команду).

Вы можете дописывать конструкции до и после данного в условии текста, но не внутри его (точнее, можете и внутри, но это будет считаться изменением — смотрите ниже условия подсчёта). Сам текст желательно менять как можно меньше.

**Ограничения:** Строки исходной программы между `begin` и `end` должны сохранять свой смысл. Они должны выполняться, и при их выполнении должно происходить в общих чертах то же, что и в исходной программе: `readln` должно считывать значения с консоли, `c := a + b` должно складывать значения двух переменных (или что там есть в вашем языке) в третью, `writeln` должно выводить правильный результат на консоль. (Это означает, что вы не можете просто закомментировать код первоначальной программы.)

**Определение победителя:** Выигрывает код, в котором исходный текст менее всего изменён по сравнению с полным первоначальным вариантом (количество добавленных символов + количество удалённых символов + количество изменённых символов), считая и строки с `program` и `end.`. Разница в больших/маленьких буквах, а также замена символа на одинаковый по начертанию (например, русское «с»/английское «c») считается за пол-символа. Если два решения имеют одинаковое количество отличий (например, ноль), выигрывает то, у которого меньше добавленного кода (в символах). Если несколько решений одинаковы и по этому критерию, выигрывает то решение, которое получит больше голосов (как обычно, «за» минус «против»).

В частности, полное совпадение кода выигрывает у неполного независимо от количества подготовительного кода.

Для того, чтобы было легче проверять ваш код, старайтесь публиковать ссылку на онлайн-компилятор с вашим кодом. Код должен компилироваться без ошибок (пусть даже с предупреждениями) и правильно работать в диапазоне входных чисел от 0 до 1000.

Продолжительность конкурса — 1 неделя.

---

Для исключения разночтений, при неясности в правилах пожалуйста переспрашивайте в комментариях или в [чате, посвящённом code golf](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39121/code-golf-----).

---

Для примера, вот внеконкурсное решение на plain TeX:

```tex
\newcount\tmp \newcount\c

\def\uncatcodeletters{\uncatcoderange{`a}{`z}\uncatcoderange{`A}{`Z}}
\def\uncatcoderange#1#2{%
  \tmp=#1 \advance\tmp -1
  \loop\advance\tmp 1 \expandafter\catcode\number\tmp=11 \ifnum\tmp<#2 \repeat}

\def\s{\begingroup\uncatcodeletters\shlp}
{\def~ := #1 + #2;{%
  \global\expandafter\c\csname #1\endcsname
  \global\expandafter\advance\expandafter\c\csname #2\endcsname
  \endgroup}
\global\let\shlp=~}

\def\inp{\begingroup\uncatcodeletters\inphelper}
\def\inphelper eadln(#1);{\endlinechar=-1 \escapechar=-1
  \expandafter\inphelperi\csname #1\endcsname\endgroup}
\def\inphelperi{\global\read16 to }

\def\out{\begingroup\uncatcodeletters\outhelper}
\def\outhelper riteln(#1);{\message{\expandafter\the\csname #1\endcsname}\endgroup}

\let\DEF\def \let\END\end
\catcode`r=13 \let r=\inp \catcode`w=13 \let w=\out
\catcode`p=14 \catcode`v=14 \catcode`b=14
\let~=\catcode ~`c=13 \let c=\s ~`e=13 \DEF end.{\END}

program test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c := a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.
```

(Если кому интересно, [гольфированный вариант](http://pastebin.com/PxhdYRuz).) Транскрипт компиляции:

```
~>tex golf.tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
(golf.tex
a=5                % <-- 5 введено с консоли

b=8                % <-- 8 введено с консоли
13 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on golf.log.
```

---

Просьба к отвечающим писать в начале решения ваш язык, количество изменённых символов и количество символов в подготовительном коде. Также просьба давать не более одного решения на ответ.

---

**Обновление:** Конкурс окончен, вот результаты.

Побеждает [ответ @Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526466/10105), сумевший уложиться в 78 подготовительных символов, и не поменять ни символа в исходном коде.

[Другой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526334/10105) того же автора выглядит чрезвычайно изящно (подключение паскалевского синтаксиса как внешний модуль, хей!), и почти выиграл приз зрительских симпатий, но проигрывает по количеству символов вследствие своей большей общности. Оба решения пользуются особенностью языка Perl, который в своих модулях позволяет предобработку текста на Perl самим Perl'ом. Мощный язык, мощные средства управления синтаксисом, заслуженная победа.

Второй в списке победителей — [ответ @Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528187/10105). Это решение продолжает идею «получить текст как строку, обработать, чтобы получился код на нужном языке, и выполнить над ней `eval`», с симпатичной, очень техничной и компактной реализацией (регулярки!).

Приз зрительских симпатий получает неожиданный [ответ @kmv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526347/10105). В этом решении текст исходной программы не объявляется строкой, а «вытягивается» из кода функции! (Это, формально говоря, решение не по стандарту, но фактически в распространённых браузерах `toString()` работает именно так.)

Третье место получает [решение @pavel с комбинацией Unix shell/C](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526736/10105), которое обходится без `eval` за счёт замены строк до компиляции и использования препроцессора C. Такой подход позволяет справиться с двоеточиями, которые вызывают затруднения для препроцессора у чистых решений на C/C++.

Вообще, идея со строкой и `eval` оказалась наиболее популярной, её реализуют также ответы @edem [Perl, построчная замена, практически интерпретация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526802/10105), @Red Skotina ([замена строк на Питоне, построчная адаптация текста, оставаясь в рамках правил, хотя и на грани](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526371/10105)), @gil9red ([то же, но более универсально, Питон](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526615/10105)), @nuts119 [на C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526392/10105) (да, в C# можно сделать `eval`, вы не знали?) и @Streletz [на Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526439/10105) (интерпретатор из сторонней библиотеки).

Тему интерпретации продолжает [ещё одно решение @nuts119](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526335/10105) на C# с использованием `DataTable` как arithmetic engine. Это решение, при всей его сложности, имеет дальний прицел на построение полноценного интерпретатора.

Оставшиеся решения на чистом C/C++ и Javascript/Typescript без `eval` вынуждены модифицировать исходный текст, хотя они смогли обойтись минимальным количеством изменений. Из этих решений наилучшие с одним удалённым символом решения @kmv [(C, препроцессор, использование битовых полей)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526755/10105) и @Qwertiy [(C++, тонкости препроцессора)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528192/10105). Интересно, что эти оба решения убирают из исходного текста соседние символы: из `:=` убрано в первом случае двоеточие, а во втором — знак `=` (!).

Оставшиеся четыре решения (@Qwertiy, [typescript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528219/10105), @pavel, [C++, препроцессор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526742/10105) (заработало больше голосов, чем победитель), снова @Qwertiy, [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528222/10105) и @Grundy, [C, препроцессор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526352/10105)) меняют больше символов в исходном коде, но также интересны и стоят вашего внимания.

Большое спасибо всем, кто принимал участие в конкурсе!

---

**Таблица лидеров:** (спасибо @Grundy за адаптацию скрипта и @jfs за идею)

```js
function getAnswers(questionId, answer_filter, page) {
  return jQuery.ajax({
    url: '//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/' + questionId + '/answers?page=' + page + '&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&site=ru.stackoverflow&filter=' + answer_filter,
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true
  }).then(function(data) {
    if (data.has_more) {

      return getAnswers(questionId, answer_filter, page + 1).then(function(d) {
        return data.items.concat(d.items);
      })
    }
    return data.items;
  });
}

function getAuthorName(e) {
  return e.owner.display_name
}

function process(items) {

  return items.map(function(item) {
    var matched = item.body.match(/<h\d+>\s*(.+?)\s*?,.*?(\d+),.*?(\d+)\s*?(?:[.;,(].*)?<\/h/);
    if (matched) {
      return {
        lang: matched[1],
        setup: +matched[2],
        changes: +matched[3],
        link: item.share_link,
        author: getAuthorName(item)

      };
    } else {
      return {
        lang: "N/A",
        setup: "N/A",
        changes: "N/A",
        link: item.share_link,
        author: getAuthorName(item)
      }
    }
  });
}

function sort(items) {
  return items.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.lang == "N/A") return 1;
    if (a.changes != b.changes) return a.changes - b.changes;
    return a.setup - b.setup;
  })
}

function fillTemplate(sortedItems) {
  $('#leadership').append(sortedItems.map(function(item, index) {
    return $('<tr>').append($('<td>').html(index + 1))
      .append($('<td>').html(item.author))
      .append($('<td>').html(item.lang))
      .append($('<td>').html(item.setup))
      .append($('<td>').html(item.changes))
      .append($('<td>').append($('<a>').attr('href', item.link).text('Link')));
  }));
  return sortedItems;
}

var QUESTION_ID = 526265,
  ANSWER_FILTER = "!4*SyY(4Kifo3Mz*lT",
  startPage = 1;
getAnswers(QUESTION_ID, ANSWER_FILTER, startPage)
  .then(process)
  .then(sort)
  .then(fillTemplate);
```

```css
#leadership {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#leadership td,
#leadership th {
  padding: 5px;
}
#leadership th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Таблица лидеров</h1>
<table id="leadership">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Автор</th>
    <th>Язык</th>
    <th>Подготовка</th>
    <th>Изменено</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: С таблицей лидеров это здорово придумано. Можно было бы подобный скрипт (ссылку на него) в описании к метке "соревнование" добавить и как им пользоваться.

Comment: @edem: Попрошу Grundy набросать описание, он разбирался со скриптом.

Comment: Ага, можно даже отдельным вопросом (ответом) этот скрипт написать, а в самой метке добавить ссылку на него.

Comment: А почему тех внеконкурсный?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Он не внеконкурсный, моё решение внеконкурсное (у меня всё-таки фора по времени).

Comment: @VladD, а с `:=` в плюсах что-то сделать можно?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Раз в конкурсе участвует размер, вот еще вариант (лично мне нравится меньше, потому как большая ориентировка именно на этот код):

<del>perl, подготовка 97, измененных 0</del>

## perl, подготовка 78, измененных 0

```
sub r{$_[0]=<>}
sub wr{print@_}
$_=q.

program test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c := a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.

;s/\b(\w)\b/\$$1/g
;s/^\S.*|.{4}n|://gm
;eval
```

[Тест на ideone](https://ideone.com/DFANsv)

В коде происходит:

1. Создаем функции r/wr аналогичные по действию паскалевским read/write ln.
2. `$_=q.` присваивает "*переменной по умолчанию*" весь текст до следующего знака `.`.
   Все последующие строки работают с этой "*переменной по умолчанию*", так как явных переменных в них не указано.
3. Перед переменными (однобуквенными словами) ставим знак `$`.
4. Удаляем строки program, var, begin, end, части названий функций (readln=r, writeln=wr), двоеточия
5. Выполняем полученный текст:

   ```
   r($a);
   r($b);
   $c = $a + $b;
   wr($c);
   ```

Answer (score 17):

## C++, Добавлено 194, изменено 2

Честное решение в 1 файл.

```
#include <iostream>
#define readln(a) std::cin>>a
#define writeln(a) std::cout << a
#define var int
#define program int main(){
#define test 
struct E{
    int n;
} end;
#define integer 
#define begin 
 
program test;
var a, b, c integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c = a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.
 
n;
}
```

Comment: Фантастический трюк с `end.n`!

Answer (score 12):

## perl, подготовка (423+17) 440, измененных 0

Включаемый модуль PascalSyntax.pm:

```
package PascalSyntax;
use Filter::Simple;
use Exporter;
@ISA=(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(var program readln writeln);
sub var(@){$_=undef for @_}
sub readln(@) {chomp($_[0]=<>);}
sub writeln(@) {print @_;}
sub program(@) {};
FILTER {
 s/:=/=/g;s/:\s+\w+//g;
 s/begin/{/g;
 s/end\.?/}/g;
 for(/var\s+(.*?);/) {
  my $t=$1; $t=~s/\s+//g;
  for (split(/,/,$t)) {
   my $var=undef;
   *{'main::'.$_}=sub():lvalue{$var};
  }
 }
};
```

Программа:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use PascalSyntax;

program test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c := a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.
```

В данном случае, зная гибкость perl я хотел что бы код работал сам по себе, с минимальными изменениями. И это при том, что в perl все переменные должны начинаться знаком `$`. Что было сделано:

1. К коду применяется модуль Filter который позволяет его менять до стадии компиляции. Он заменяет begin и end на фигурные скобки (можно было не делать, объявив функции с этими именами). И удаляются `:` так как других способов их использовать я не нашел (в perl нет оператора "двоеточие" и перегрузить его нельзя).
2. Тот же filter анализирует строку `var` и создает в основной программе функции с именами переменных. Возвращающих каждая свою переменную, созданную в замыкании. Функции имеют атрибут `lvalue`, позволяющий присваивать значения возвращаемым ими переменным (конструкция `c()=a()+b()` становится рабочей, а круглые скобки для известных на момент компиляции функций не обязательны)
3. Для остальных ключевых слов паскаля (program, var, read/writeln) созданы функции.

Comment: Ого! А есть online-компилятор? (Или с двумя файлами невозможно?)

Comment: @VladD Ну да, для онлайна хз как второй файл подцепить. А без второго файла фильтр не работает :( По крайней мере я не придумал как его без модуля запустить

Comment: [Вот вроде есть возможность](http://goo.gl/Bhl3Ts), но у меня что-то не компилируется (не видит `Filter::Simple`).

Comment: @VladD Кстати по вашей ссылке открывается пустой проект. Т.е. второй файл там есть в списке но увидеть его нельзя. И в main hello только. Там в принципе wget есть я даже Filter::Simple скачал, только он еще модули тянет за собой. И качать из все как то криво. А модулья CPAN что бы автоматом доставлять модули там то же нет. Сильно урезанный.

Comment: Ага, я заметил. У них какая-то проблема с публикацией, видимо. Или настройки моего браузера подкачали.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/perl` - эту строку можно смело убрать, так как при запуске итак указываем `perl test.pl`. `use lib './';` и эту строку тоже, так как текущий каталог `.` уже находится в списке путей для поиска модулей: `perl -E 'say $INC[-1]'`

Comment: @edem Я знаю, поэтому не считал первую строку в размер добавляемого кода :) но лично мне первая строка нужна. Я при работе делаю файл исполнимым и просто нажимаю на нем enter в mc, он запускается за счет первой строки. По use lib действительно интересно, у меня сейчас точка то же есть в путях. Но помню когда то были проблемы ...

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript, подготовка (без форматирования 223+5) 228, Изменено: 0

Текст программы все же можно поместить в комментарий, не нарушая ограничения на задание, если затем этот текст можно извлечь и выполнить. Данное решение применяет этот подход. Комментарий был использован, поскольку в JavaScript нет here-document синтаксиса для строк.

Что происходит:

- Весь текст функции, включая комментарии, в JavaScript может быть преобразован в строку. Через `f.toString()` получаем текст функции, в теле которой находится комментарий с программой.
- Первый `replace` удаляет первые 4 и последние 2 строки.
- Второй `replace` оборачивает аргументы у `readln` и `writeln` в кавычки. Используется факт того, что `c` также попадает в `window` как глобальная переменная.
- Третий убирает двоеточие.

Посмотреть можно [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/d1hqrxnw/). Проверял на Firefox, Chrome.

Код с форматированием:

```
(function (f) {
    var readln = function (x) {
        window[x] = +prompt()
    };
    var writeln = function (x) {
        alert(window[x])
    };
    eval(f.toString()
        .replace(/(.+\n){4}([\s\S]+)en[^]+$/, '$2')
        .replace(/\((.)\)/g, '("$1")')
        .replace(':', '')
    )
})(function(){/*
program test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c := a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.
*/});
```

Comment: Ох, то есть в JS можно из функции достать комментарии? о_О

Comment: @VladD, тут просто текст функции в строку. поэтому все что было то и будет

Comment: Это не по стандарту. Некоторые движки не позволят достать текст функции.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: А если `/*...*/` заменить на `"..."`? Или это относится к любой части функции, а не только к комментарию?

Comment: @VladD к любой части функции.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Окей, тогда придётся просто менять на строковой литерал?

Comment: @VladD ага, так будет лучше

Comment: @PavelMayorov: И кажется короче на пару символов. Хотя и не так изящно.

Comment: то же самое будет работать и на php

Comment: О этом нюансе узнал из изучения `AngularJS`. Крутой продукт, а узнавал что передать в `callback` просто переводя функцию в строку и выдирая регуляркой имена аргументов. Стыд просто (для них); поговаривают что функции в стандарте обяжут выдавать всё тело.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, какие же? Текст функции вполне по стандарту, если функция не нативная.

Answer (score 8):

## C, подготовка 157, изменено 1

<del>C, подготовка 159, 162, 187, 196, изменено 1.</del>

От одного двоеточия удалось избавиться, используя битовые поля в структуре. Для второго двоеточия ничего придумать не смог. :)

Код [здесь](https://ideone.com/llLBsZ).

```
#define test
#define var struct{int
#define integer 1;}end;a,b,c
#define begin main(){
#define readln(x) scanf("%d",&x)
#define writeln(x) printf("%d",x)

program test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c = a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.

a;}
```

После обработки препроцессором:

```
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.c"

program;
struct{int a, b, c: 1;}end;a,b,c;
main(){
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%d",&b);
    c = a + b;
    printf("%d",c);
end.

a;}
```

Comment: будет короче, если создание `p` поместить сразу в макрос `integer` --> `1;} p ;int a,b,c` как-то так. А из `begin` оставить `int main(){` как-то так. https://ideone.com/ZHoS6e

Comment: @pavel действительно :)

Comment: да сразу ужё всё копируй, `#define end p` убирай а переменную `end` назови :)

Comment: @pavel еще int у main можно не указывать

Comment: https://ideone.com/ZHoS6e и не только у `int` тут нормально компилируется

Comment: ещё 3 символа заменять не `program` а `test`

Answer (score 7):

## C++, добавлено 252, изменено 1 (и это не двоеточие!)

https://ideone.com/WxCd1s

```
#include <iostream>

#define program int
#define test main(){
#define var int
#define v(t) integer=a+b;u##t
#define z(t) v(t)
#define c z(__LINE__)
#define begin
#define readln std::cin>>
#define writeln(x) std::cout<<integer
#define end std::cin

program test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c : a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.

get();}
```

Answer (score 6):

## C#, Подготовка 804, Измененных 0

Написано не оптимально. На Mono не запустится. Но можно добавить еще "известных" конструкций и изменить выражение. Неидеальное решение для конкурса :)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using VarIntegers = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>;

namespace Q526265_MyAnswer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void RunProgram(string textProgram)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            VarIntegers vars = new VarIntegers();
            Func<string, string> getVarName = str => Regex.Match(str, @"\(([\w]+)\)").Groups[1].Value;
            foreach (var item in textProgram.Replace("\r\n", "").Split(';'))
            {
                if (item.Contains("readln"))
                    vars[getVarName(item)] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                else if (item.Contains("writeln"))
                    Console.WriteLine(vars[getVarName(item)]);
                else if (item.Contains(":="))
                {
                    var exp = Regex.Split(item.Replace(" ", ""), ":=");
                    vars[exp[0]] = (int)dt.Compute(Regex.Replace(exp[1], @"[\w]+", m => vars[m.ToString()].ToString()), "");
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {

            RunProgram(@"
program test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c := a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.
");
            RunProgram(@"
program test;
var number1, number2, number3: integer;
begin
    readln(number1);
    readln(number2);
    number3 := number1 * number2 - (number1 + number2);
    writeln(number3);
end.
");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Честный интерпретатор, чё, круто. (Ну ладно, почти честный.)

Comment: А `DataTable` вы используете для `eval`'а, правильно?

Comment: @VladD, да. Не мог придумать больше, чтобы уменьшить код.

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript ES6, добавлено 100, изменено 0

```js
readln=prompt,writeln=alert;eval(`
program test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c := a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.
`.replace(/^[pbe].*|: ?\w*/gm,"").replace(/\w+\((.)\)/g,"$1=+$&"))
```

Answer (score 6):

## Typescript, добавлено <s>127</s> 120, изменено 2

[Песочница](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20type%20integer%3Dany%0D%0A~function(a%2Cb%2Cwriteln%2Cend)%7Bvar%20test%2Cbegin%2Cu%3Darguments%2Creadln%3Di%3D%3Eu%5Bi%5D%3D%2Bprompt()%2C%0D%0A%0D%0Aprogram%3Dtest%3B%0D%0Avar%20a%2C%20b%2C%20c%3A%20integer%3B%0D%0Abegin%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readln(a)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readln(b)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%20%3D%20a%20%2B%20b%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20writeln(c)%3B%0D%0Aend.%0D%0A%0D%0Aa%7D(0%2C1%2Calert%2C%7B%7D))

```
declare type integer=any
~function(a,b,writeln,end){var test,begin,u=arguments,readln=i=>u[i]=+prompt(),

program=test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c = a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.

a}(0,1,alert,{})
```

## Javascript ES6, добавлено <s>93</s> 86, изменено 3

Аналогичная идея, но с несколькими глобальными переменными:

```js
~function(a,b,writeln,end,test,begin){readln=i=>arguments[i]=+prompt()
  
program=test;
var a, b, c, integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c = a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.

a}(0,1,alert,{})
```

Значение по умолчанию использовать нельзя, т. к. оно разрывает связь `arguments` с именами.

Answer (score 5):

## [c](/questions/tagged/c), Подготовка: 180, изменено 5

```
#define program
#define test
#define begin int main(void){
#define end }
#define var(a,b,c,...) int a,b,c
#define readln(a) scanf_s("%d",&a)
#define writeln(a) printf("%d",a)

program test;
var(a, b, c, : integer);
begin
readln(a);
readln(b);
c = a + b;
writeln(c);
end
```

Comment: Первые две строки можно заменить на `#define program int`

Comment: @kmv, честно говоря, не вижу особого смысла

Comment: сумел сократить изменения до 2 символов (убрал :), дальше не выходит http://ideone.com/QOdGHT

Comment: @pavel, зато подготовка увеличилась :-)

Comment: @Grundy на критерии то сначала по изменениям потом по подготовке :) Есть мысли что с : можно сделать?) Я тернарник пытался прикрутить но это ужас.

Comment: @pavel, с двоеточием можно сделать метку под goto. Но вот что с `:=` сделать, я так и не придумал, поэтому пришлось равно [выкинуть](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/528192/178988)))))

Answer (score 5):

## Java, Подготовка: >1500 (точно затрудняюсь подсчитать) 1500, Изменено:0

Небольшой пример трансляции с Pascal на Java с последующим выполнением результата на лету при помощи библиотеки [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/).

Считаю, что написано далеко не идеально, так как не обладает достаточной гибкостью.

Особенность решения - синтаксис Pascal в незначительной степени сохранён и в результирующем коде на Java.

Класс Engine (реализует требуемый функционал):

```
import bsh.EvalError;
import java.io.IOException;
import bsh.Interpreter;

public class Engine {

//Задание с ru.SO, скопированное без каких-либо изменений
private final String sourcePascal = "program test;\nvar a, b, c: integer;\nbegin\n    readln(a);\n    readln(b);\n    c := a + b;\n    writeln(c);\nend.";

private final String classPrefix = "public class Test{";
private String methodPrefix = "public void testMethod(){";
private final String postfix = "}";
private final String readln = "private int readln(){Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);return in.nextInt();}";
private final String writeln = "private void writeln(int a){System.out.println(a);}";
private final String engineScript = "Test t = new Test();t.testMethod();";

private String translateToJava(String source) {
    String preparedCode = source.substring(source.indexOf(";") + 1).replace(":=", "=").replace("var a, b, c: integer", "int a,b,c").replace("begin", "{").replace("end.", "}").replace("readln(a)", "a=readln()").replace("readln(b)", "b=readln()");
    String methodScript = methodPrefix +preparedCode+ postfix;
    String classScript = classPrefix + readln + writeln + methodScript + postfix;
    String result = classScript + engineScript;
    return result;
}

public void run() throws IOException, EvalError {        
    Interpreter i = new Interpreter();
    i.eval(translateToJava(sourcePascal));
}
}
```

Использование класса Engine:

```
Engine en =new Engine();
en.run();
```

Результирующий код на Java, в который механизмы класса Engine превращают задание на Pascal:

```
public class Test{private int readln(){Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);return in.nextInt();}private void writeln(int a){System.out.println(a);}public void testMethod(){
int a,b,c;
{
    a=readln();
    b=readln();
    c = a + b;
    writeln(c);
}}}Test t = new Test();t.testMethod();
```

Comment: Ого, настоящий интерпретатор? Вы взяли в руки мощное оружие.

Comment: @VladD, я бы пока не назвал это полноценным интерпретатором. Всё-таки данное решение больше заточено под конкретную задачу. Но, при желании, его можно развить.

Comment: Я понимаю, тем более, что есть ограничение на количество символов. Но сам подход очень хорош.

Answer (score 4):

## Python3, подготовка 423, измененных 0

```
code_pas = '''\
program test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c := a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.'''

code_pas = code_pas.split('\n')
code_pas = code_pas[3:7]
code_pas[0] = code_pas[0].replace('    readln(a);','a = int(input())')
code_pas[1] = code_pas[1].replace('    readln(b);','b = int(input())')
code_pas[2] = code_pas[2].replace('    c := a + b;','c = a +b')
code_pas[3] = code_pas[3].replace('    writeln(c);','print(c)')
code = '\n'.join(code_pas)
co = compile(code,'','exec')
exec(co)
```

http://ideone.com/fGsz4n

Вариант вне конкурса:

```
code_pas = '''\
program test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c := a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.'''
code_py = '''\
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = a + b
print(c)'''

code = code_pas.replace(code_pas, code_py)
co = compile(code,'','exec')
exec(co)
```

http://ideone.com/L4ilJD

Answer (score 4):

## C#

Еще один вариант, здесь уже pascal код транслируется в c# код, который затем компилируется и запускается.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Q526265_MyAnswer2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void RunProgram(string pascalProgram)
        {
            string className = "Program";
            Func<string, string> pascalType2SharpType = pascalType =>
            {
                switch (pascalType)
                {
                    case "integer":
                        return "int";
                }
                return "object";
            };
            var sharpProgram = Regex.Replace(pascalProgram, @"program (\w+);", m => { className = m.Groups[1].Value; return m.Result(@"
                using System;
                class $1 {
                    static void readln(ref int variable) {
                        variable = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    static void writeln(int value) {
                        Console.WriteLine(value);
                    }
            "); });
            sharpProgram = Regex.Replace(sharpProgram, @"var (.*): (\w+);", m => m.Result("static " + pascalType2SharpType(m.Groups[2].Value) + " $1;"));
            sharpProgram = Regex.Replace(sharpProgram, @"readln\((\w+)\)", "readln(ref $1)");
            sharpProgram = sharpProgram.Replace("begin", "static void Main() {").Replace("end.", "}}").Replace(":=", "=");

            object programObject = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider()
                .CompileAssemblyFromSource(new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters(), sharpProgram)
                .CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(className);
            programObject.GetType().GetMethod("Main", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(null, null);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunProgram(@"
program test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c := a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.
");
            RunProgram(@"
program MyProgram;
var a, b, c, d: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    readln(d);
    c := (a + b) / d;
    writeln(c);
end.
");    
        }
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/Dt0WhE

Более короткий вариант:
https://ideone.com/jwdByx

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript ES6, добавлено <s>86</s> 79, изменено 3 (без `eval`)

```js
begin=end=test=writeln=alert;with(o={a:'a',b:'b',readln(x){o[x]=+prompt()}}){

program=test;
var a, b, c, integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c = a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.

a}
```

Answer (score 3):

**python3:**

```
code = """\
program test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c := a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.
"""\
.replace('program test;', '')\
.replace('var a, b, c: integer;', '')\
.replace('begin', '')\
.replace('end.', '')\
.replace('    ', '')\
.replace(':=', '=')\
.replace('writeln', 'print')\
.strip()

import re
code = re.sub('readln\((.+)\);', r'\1 = int(input())', code)

exec(code)
```

Замена операндов / операторов на аналогичные. Для замены `readln` используется регулярка.

Answer (score 3):

## sh/С, Подготовка: ~175, Изменено:0

Не знаю насколько это честно и как считать.

```
echo '
Dreadln(a) scanf("%d",&a);
Dwriteln(a) printf("%d",a);
Dvar int
Dtest
Dinteger
Dbegin main(){
Dend ;
program test;
var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c := a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.
}' | sed 's/[.:]//g' | sed 's/D/#define /g'| gcc -x c - -o 1 && ./1
```

Параметры заголовка примерные, возможно можно ещё улучшить. Спасибо чатику за идеи.

Comment: Вы забыли #define end. А запускать все можно и одной строчкой: `cat a.c | sed 's/[.:]//g' | g++ -x c++ - -o 1 && ./1`

Comment: @Mike За команду спасибо :)

Comment: @Mike: [UUoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) же! `<a.c sed 's/[.:]//g' | g++ -x c++ - -o 1 && ./1`.

Comment: @VladD Тогда еще проще `sed 's/[.:]//g' a.c | g++...`

Comment: @Mike: Точно! А ещё, если экономить символы в `runner`, можно переименовать файл в однобуквенное имя.

Comment: @VladD у меня без расширения не компилирует)

Comment: @pavel: Но `runner` же (в версиях из комментариев) всё равно передаёт файл через pipe?

Comment: @VladD в изначальном варианте нет, просто берёт из уже составленного файла.

Comment: @pavel: Угу, покатит только для варианта из комментариев. Или с `-x c++`.

Comment: @VladD Кстати, второй файл вообще не нужен !!! Файл с программой должен начинаться `#!/bin/bash`, вторая строка `echo '` и в конец файла надо добавить строку `' | sed 's/[.:]//g' | g++ -x c++ - -o 1 && ./1` при запуске такого текстового файла он будет скомпилирован и запущен

Comment: @Mike: Гениально! // Ещё `chmod +x` по идее.

Comment: что-то мне кажется сейчас на `bash` сделают решение в этом чате :)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, Добавлено 304, Изменено 0

```
p('
program test;

var a, b, c: integer;
begin
    readln(a);
    readln(b);
    c := a + b;
    writeln(c);
end.
');

sub p {
    # Получаем токены.
    while (my $s = substr($_[0], $i++, 1)) {
        $s !~ /\s/ ? $t .= $s : $t ne '' ? ((push @t, $t) and ($t='')):();
    }

    # Анализируем их, составляя текстовый аналог pascal программы для perl.
    for (my $i=0; $i < @t; $i++) {
        $e .= '$'.substr($t[$i],7,1).'=<>;' if $t[$i]=~/^readln/;
        $e .= '$'.$t[$i-1].'=$'.$t[$i+1].$t[$i+2].'$'.$t[$i+3] if $t[$i] eq ':=';  
        $e .= 'print$'. (substr($t[$i], 8, 1)).';' if $t[$i]=~/^writeln/;
    }

    # Выполняем программу.
    eval $e;
}
```