# Помогите пожалуйста перевести код с Pascal на С++

Tags: c++, pascal

Помогите пожалуйста перевести код с Pascal на С++

```
   uses crt;
   var
    a,b,c,d,e,f,m,g:integer;
   begin
    write('введите a=');readln(a);
    write('введите b=');readln(b);
    write('введите c=');readln(c);
    write('введите d=');readln(d);
    write('введите e=');readln(e);
    write('введите f=');readln(f);
    m:=(a*c*f)-(a*e*e)-(b*b*f)+(b*e*d)+(d*b*e)-(d*c*d);
    g:=(a*c)-(b*b);
    if (m<>0) and(g>0) then writeln('Вид графика эллипс')
    else if (m<>0) and(g<0) then writeln('Вид графика гипербола')
    else if (m<>0) and(g=0) then writeln('Вид графика парабола')
    else if (m=0) and (g>0) then writeln('Вид графика две мнимые прямые')
    else if (m=0) and (g<0) then writeln('Вид графика две пересекающиеся прямые')
    else if (m=0) and (g=0) then writeln('Вид графика две параллельные прямые');
   end.
```

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/526265/10105 :)

Comment: @VladD не следует путать вопросы "как сделать" и вопросы-соревнования (на английском эти вопросы даже на *разных* сайтах задаются). Ваш комментарий не выглядит что он сделан  "in good faith" (вопрос  не codegolf). Проблема с данным вопросом, что он слишком общий: автор не указал с какой именно конструкцией у него проблемы. "Как readln(m)  из Паскаля на С++ перевести" можно один раз задать. Вопрос в текущем виде (и ему подобные) следует закрыть (и удалить) -- как слишком общий (если вы как я верите, что человек сможет в будущем более сфокусированные вопросы задавать) или как homework если нет.

Comment: @jfs: Ну это была шутка, что ж вы так серьёзно. Я даже смайлик поставил.

Comment: @jfs: Проблема с данным вопросом в том, что он не содержит вопроса.

Comment: @jfs: По моему опыту, человек, выкладывающий дамп задания, не возвращается на сайт.

Comment: @jfs Как мне кажется, все вопросы с просьбой перевести код из любого языка на любой другой можно закрывать как дубликаты вопроса, указанного VladD, либо закрывать/удалять сразу. Идея, конечно же, не в соревновании, а, скорее, показывает авторам таких вопросов тот способ решения, который может предложить им сообщество.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: VladD говорит, что это шутка. Шутка это неадекватный ответ на вопрос, который не подходит для сайта: не нужно над автором издеваться, вместо того, чтобы указать какие вопросы являются допустимыми на сайте и что автор может сделать, чтобы задать полезный вопрос. Если сузить вопрос или разбить его на несколько фундаментальных, как я предложил выше, то могли бы полезные вопросы получиться. Нет смысла в том, чтобы каждый программист каждый раз заново решал задачу как readln из Паскаля на C++ выразить (это может быть тривиально или могут быть платформо-зависимые тонкости).

Comment: @jfs Конечно же, мы (я – точно, думаю и VladD тоже) ни коем образом не хотим как–либо подшучивать над авторами. Идея была в том, чтобы закрывать однотипные вопросы как дубликат. Если я не ошибаюсь, вопрос, указанный в комментариях появился именно по аналогичной причине.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky мой самый первый комментарий о том что это не дубликат. На что VladD *буквально* ответил: *«Ну это была шутка, что ж вы так серьёзно. Я даже смайлик поставил.»* что только подтверждает что это не дубликат. (Тем более что вопрос в текущем виде следует удалить — он слишком обширный (ответ: книги по С++, Pascal)  —  уже только поэтому он не может иметь дубликатов так как такие вопросы также  по той же причине удалить следует). Если три опытных участника не могут договориться, то это только подтверждает что не следует шутить, а явно указать что делать/как улучшить вопрос.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale (LC_ALL, "rus");
int a,b,c,d,e,f,m,g;
cout<<"ВВедите a\n";
cin>>a;
cout<<"ВВедите b\n";
cin>>b;
cout<<"ВВедите c\n";
cin>>c;
cout<<"ВВедите d\n";
cin>>d;
cout<<"ВВедите e\n";
cin>>e;
cout<<"ВВедите f\n";
cin>>f;
m=(a*c*f)-(a*e*e)-(b*b*f)+(b*e*d)+(d*b*e)-(d*c*d);
g=(a*c)-(b*b);
if (m!=0 && g>0)
cout<<"Вид графика элипс\n";
if (m!=0 && g<0) 
cout<<"Вид графика гиперболa\n";
if (m!=0 && g==0) 
cout<<"Вид графика парабола\n";
if (m==0 && g>0)
cout<<"Вид графика две мнимые прямые\n";
if (m==0 && g<0 )
cout<<"Вид графика две пересекающиеся прямые";
if (m==0 && g==0) 
cout<<"Вид графика две параллельные прямые";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!